# google maps apis-- JQuery & using Places libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a little hacked-together web app that uses the google maps api to draw data from a database and create and display markers and associated data on an embedded map, using JSON objects. I'm accessing the api here:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

I've now realized I need a search box on the map, so users search for an address and the map will shift to display their desired location. Seems like I need the Places library, I can really easily implement a search box using the code samples in the documentation. I don't care about the Places themselves or doing anything with them, just identifying the location and shifting the resetting the bounds to that desired location. So I need to access the places library, which apparently is here:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false

BUT, my previous code (perhaps not surprisingly) breaks if I switch out the libraries. Is there any way to use both? Do I have to deal with Places is some other way because I'm already using JQuery for this app? Or is it just a problem with how I'm referring to the libraries?

Thanks! z

Answer (score 0):

Simply Do this

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;
var lat;
var lng;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
  {           
    lat= results[0].geometry.location.latitude;
    lng =results[0].geometry.location.longitude;
  }
});
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
map.setZoom(14);
```

Comment: Thanks! Just generally, is it actually bad practice to include multiple references to different google maps apis (if I'm doing utilizing separate functionality), or is the warning I get just a caution?